# Rails - Creating a model and its nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, model, nested-attributes, nested-resources

I'm trying to create a Gallery model and its `has_many` associations by passing the following to `create`.

```
[
  {
    "title":"Some Titler",
    "description":"",
    "date":"18-3-2012",
    "photographs":[
      {
        "title": "Some Title",
        "camera": "Canon 600D"
      },
      {
        "title": "Some Other Title",
        "camera": "Canon 600D"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Without the nested `photographs` array, it works fine, but with it, I get an error:

```
Photograph(#70242279271180) expected, got Hash(#70242248401160)
```

What is wrong with the syntax?

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date, :description, :published, :title


  has_many :photographs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photographs

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 "photographs":[]
```

to

```
 "photographs_attributes":[]
```

Comment: Damn it. That's got me before. Thanks a lot.